# Unit testing dynamic queries in Entity Framework 4

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-4, dynamicquery, dynamic-queries

When implementing a Unit of Work pattern with entity framework 4.0, what is the correct design to give the ability to create dynamic queries with CreateQuery method of the object context? And by correct I mean designing somehow that I can use it in unit test with mock objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you mean by "correct" it depends on your situation, but the general answer is that you will need some abstractions that can be replaced during test. For some inspiration, here is what we use (we use self tracking poco entities)

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Object context interface for abstracting the service layer from the
/// implementation details of object storage.
/// </summary>
public interface IObjectContext : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the entity objects of the given type known by this object context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of the entity.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The instances of the given type already loaded into this object context</returns>
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetManagedEntities<TEntity>() where TEntity : EntityBase;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an object set for the provided entity type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of the entity.</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IObjectSet<TEntity> CreateObjectSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : EntityBase;

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies the changes made to the provided entity object graph to this object context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of entity (inferred).</typeparam>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity object graph that has been modified.</param>
    void ApplyChanges<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : EntityBase, IObjectWithChangeTracker;

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the changes known by this object context instance to the database.
    /// </summary>
    void Save();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new logical unit of work spanning a single business transaction.
    /// </summary>
    IUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new logical unit of work spanning a single business transaction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isolationLevel">The transaction isolation level used by the
    /// unit of work ambient transaction.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel isolationLevel);
}
```

and for abstracting transactions

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Interface abstraction for a unit of work, aka all persistent work spanning a single
/// business transaction and to be performed in unity.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Used to support outer and inner units of work where one outer UoW may consist
/// of multiple nested inner UoW instances and have all of them share a transaction.</remarks>
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the transaction isolation level used by the unit of work ambient transaction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The isolation level.</value>
    IsolationLevel IsolationLevel { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the transaction timeout time span used by the unit of work ambient transaction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The transaction timeout duration.</value>
    TimeSpan TransactionTimeout { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Completes the unit of work that this instance represents.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// For an outer unit of work, will persist all changes represented by this business
    /// transaction and will then signal the ambient transaction in use as complete.
    /// For an inner unit of work, will signal itself as completed to the outer unit of
    /// work that it is part of.
    /// </remarks>
    void Complete();
}
```

then modify the object context generation code to support these interfaces + implement your UoW according to your needs (our implementation omitted for brevity). HTH